# Fiddler websocket data preview issue

Tags: fiddler

I have issue with viewing webscocket data in fiddler. I exprienced it for a long time, probably one year or so.
The issue is I see some unredable chars in websocket tab instead of json.

the data looks like: < 1 0E  B Tj ^  BbADbG$  w Y      ...
[image: Screenshot]
I am sure that server send json text, as I can see this in chrome dev tools(network tab).
I think there are can be few reasons of this issue:

- bug in fiddler
- some options in fiddler wasn't enabled
- text encoding issue
- some data compression which enabled on server side and fiddler do not aware of it

I am not sure but seems I never had such issue in old versions of Fiddler.

Does anyone have same issue as I have?

My current version:

Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger

v4.6.20171.14978
Built: 21 March 2017

64-bit AMD64, VM: 65.0mb, WS: 100.0mb
.NET 4.6.2 WinNT 6.1.7601 SP1

Answer (score 1):

It's because the WebSocket server accept extension and in particular the per-message compression extension. Up to know Fiddler doesn't de-compressed the frame message so in order to debug your application you must use Chrome developer tools or disable the per-message compression Server Side. You could also ignore all the client extension in the server so that the compression won't be enabled.